# Bitcoin - Error message every time I open wallet please help! Win 10

Tags: bitcoin-core

Windows 10 system.

Every time i open Bitcoin Core version 0.15.1 I get this message.

Cannot obtain a lock on data directory C:. Bitcoin Core is probably already running. The system cannot find the file specified..

I have checked Task manager and nothing is running, I have even deleted the lock file as someone else previously mentioned else where, I have turned computer off and on still no different.

Comment: Run as administrator fixed my problem.

Comment: Hello user68196, please don't use comments to answer questions. Since you yourself solved your problem, please post an answer post on your question to allow other users to learn from your question. Thanks!